# How to use S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval with boto3?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, boto3, amazon-glacier

As described in the boto3 documentation, S3 Glacier storage class can be accessed by using the following command:

```py
import boto3

client = boto3.client('glacier')
```

But actually I can't find any parameters or clients to activate instant retrieval storage class, that is new since november 2021.

Is it possible to create Glacier Instant Retrieval buckets with boto3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just use regular [get_object](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/s3.html#S3.Client.get_object) `S3` (not `glacier`) call to get files from  S3 Glacier Instant Retrieval class.

Comment: Okay,Is it possible to create the glacier instant retrieval bucket with boto3 as well?

Comment: @dl.meteo The class is related to objects, not buckets. When you `put_object` in `boto3`, you can specify storage class.